# Построение графика функции.

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Есть уравнение многомодальной функции. Нужно построить ее график. Условие такое: для построения графика использовать метод SetPixel(int x, int y, int color);
(координаты и цвет устанавливаемого пикселя). Проблема в том, что если идти только по одной оси и ставить пиксели, то график отрисовывается не полностью, а если по обеим, то выполняется лишняя работа. В сети по этому вопросу находится только "Постоить графики онлайн" и т.п. Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Можете подкинуть литературу или дать алгоритм?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Берете любой алгоритм для прорисовки линий по точкам, например [Алгоритм Брезенхэма](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0). Дальше, выбираете такое смещение по оси х, что бы попадать в каждый пиксель (или через один-два - все сильно зависит от функции и ее поведения).  Там, на википедии есть готовые алгоритмы и код. Для построения они как раз и пользуются только установкой пикселей.

Если внешний вид будет неудовлетворительным, тогда придется изучить [кривые Безье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5). Но я думаю, что этого не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Делал такюю штуку, но для уравнений второго порядка only, так что могу лишь дать направление для поиска.
Решение зависит от того, какая функция. Можно либо анализировать функцию и приближать ее параболами, либо создать инструмент для построения отрезка и line(x, f(x), x+step, f(x+step)). Если функция не существует в какой-то точке, при втором способе начинаются проблемы.